# I'm having issues posting my first question on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, posting

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but to be honest this post is mostly to test to see if the problem is with the body of my question.

Every time I ask my question on Stack Overflow, I get a "The connection was reset" browser error message.

I'm logged in using a Google OpenID, though I have the same problem when I try as an anonymous user.

Edit: my question to meta went through, however the main site remains a problem. I notice that I am not being prompted with the reCAPTCHA screen on the main post.

Comment: What browser, OS version?

Comment: Win7 using Firefox 3.6, latest version of Chrome, and IE8 all have the same issues.

The question in question is right here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106135/hibernate-cascading-delete-with-lazy-loaded-tree-nodes

I gave up trying to post the full body as certain blocks of plain text repeatedly end in problems.  Not sure if it has anything to do with the actual body of text, or if I'm just really unlucky hitting a cluster problem, but as it stands even if I remove certain lines of text from that question the edit will fail.

Comment: @jzd Just as a matter of curiosity, why do people ask what OS?  Every support thing people ask for OS, I even do when someone says something doesn't work, but has that info ever lead to a solution?!

Comment: @Tom mostly useful for repeatability. Running Firefox 3.6 on Windows vs Linux could have different results.  Which means a user could have a problem that is only specific to the Windows side, therefore if possible the solution should be verified on the same OS/Browser if the problem is specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am 99.9% sure this is a proxy or firewall interfering with the post. We've seen this many times before.

Comment: I'm not sure why the proxy would block some requests and not others.  In my case I was able to finally create the submission, however the full text is still not accepted by stackoverflow via edit.  I can't even remove the section in parenthesis following my block of code showing my hibernate mapping without the request failing.

Comment: @aproctor badly written proxies/firewalls/antivirus try to "protect" you from script injection, etc. We see this *all the time*. It's really quite boring.

Comment: I just was able to post the full question from my home computer.  My guess is  you're right and it was a proxy issue, though I still don't understand the difference in my request text that would cause a problem.